# react-native run-android isnt working [Ubuntu 20.04] **FIXED**

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

every time i start a new RN project and start to run the android emulator it shows this error :

Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Could not write standard input to Gradle build daemon.

I did everything and nothing seems to work!

**Fixed**

1. I just had to add a local. proprieties file in my android root project folder and add the Sdk Path. " sdk dir = /home/USERNAME/android/Sdk "
2. Update the ./bash_profile [./profile] file with the ANDROID_HOME path tools
3. and do a sudo ./gradlew clean command

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Android studio is installed and you have an emulator or device started ?
Screenshoot of the error ?
What gives the command : `adb devices` ?

Comment: Yes it is installed and when i do adb devices it shows my emulator and my phone they are both correctly connected

Comment: Just connect one device. And you have a screenshaot of the complete console error ?

Comment: i just uploaded the screenshot below :)

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my emulator and when i do `adb devices` it shows that it recognized and connected

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw3PM.png